# What is the best/correct way to merge a hotfix based off on production/master branch, into development which is several commits ahead?

Tags: git

As mentioned in the title, I've done a recent hotfix on a new branch based off the production branch and merged it to production. Now I have to merge this new hotfix branch, also onto development branch (we have no release branch). But the development branch is ahead by several commits (fixes, features). The pull request shows me that those changes will be overwritten by the incoming hotfix branch changes.

So what is the best/correct way to merge only that single hotfix onto my development branch , the rest remaining the same? And what is the professional way to merge hotfixes back into the development branch? Any standard/recommended ways would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wouldn't have done it this way.  I would have fixed in the development branch, then rebased production on development.  Since you did it this way, maybe your only option is to cherry pick the fix onto development.

Comment: What do you mean "we have no release branch"? You released something into production!  That's your release branch.

Comment: @William Im sorry , I meant we have no dedicated release branches.  Just development and production branches. We merge dev into prod and release. So yeah our dev branch is the release branch.

Comment: At work, we merge master to release and develop after a hotfix. It shouldn't introduce any other changes.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I didnt have much time, but many articles (eg.  https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model) said you should branch off the master or production branch, for live critical hotfixes , merge them into master, and then later merge into development. I just followed that , and now I was just wondering if that's the standard, how do you merge that back into a dev branch which is already so much ahead. Cherry pick would work , but is that the recommended way/ industry standard?

Comment: Maybe you could a) fix the bug in a hotfix branch and merge to master, and then b) rebase the dev branch against master, bringing in the hotfix.